# use jq to return a boolean if more than one key has a specified value

Tags: json, jq, repeat

I have a JSON blob. It contains a queue of items to process. I am using jq to filter it. Each object in this queue has the key `downloadId`. I can return a list of objects where `downloadId` has a certain value with this filter:

```
.[] | select((.downloadId) == "ABCA01479FCAB77D0A8A5C499D5ABAA147E97B47")
```

But what I really need is a boolean that will return `true` if there is more than one object in the queue with that value for `downloadId`. I've been looking over the jq manual but I'm not quite sure how to do that. I can try using `any`

```
any(.[]; .downloadId == "ABCA01479FCAB77D0A8A5C499D5ABAA147E97B47")
```

but that returns true if there is one instance of that value, not more than one.

Here is a blob:

```
[
  {
    "sizeleft": 805679928.0,
    "timeleft": "00:00:00",
    "estimatedCompletionTime": "2019-05-03T17:30:31.370856Z",
    "status": "Paused",
    "trackedDownloadStatus": "Ok",
    "statusMessages": [],
    "downloadId": "1C2DE46A5B4258BE7AC47FEFAE71432897417126",
    "id": 1065601863
  },
  {
    "sizeleft": 836459293.0,
    "timeleft": "00:00:00",
    "estimatedCompletionTime": "2019-05-03T17:30:31.370864Z",
    "status": "Paused",
    "trackedDownloadStatus": "Ok",
    "statusMessages": [],
    "downloadId": "728084A13FD172FED437C6AE503A8CF4A8D317AE",
    "id": 1177597916
  },
  {
    "sizeleft": 836459293.0,
    "timeleft": "00:00:00",
    "estimatedCompletionTime": "2019-05-03T17:30:31.370864Z",
    "status": "Paused",
    "trackedDownloadStatus": "Ok",
    "statusMessages": [],
    "downloadId": "ABCA01479FCAB77D0A8A5C499D5ABAA147E97B47",
    "id": 1177597916
  }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve an efficient solution, let us define `repeated/2` to check whether a given value occurs more than once in a stream:

```
def repeated(stream; $value):
  label $done
  | foreach stream as $x (0;
       if $x == $value then  . + 1 else . end;
       if . == 2 then true, break $done else empty end)
  // false;
```

The key here is of course to break out of the loop once the value has been encountered a second time.

### Solution

With the above, the solution would be:

```
repeated(.[] | .downloadId; "ABCA01479FCAB77D0A8A5C499D5ABAA147E97B47")
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by your response since I'm not very familiar with the more complex features of jq. Where would I plug in `downloadId` and `ABCA01479FCAB77D0A8A5C499D5ABAA147E97B47`?

Comment: I added a sample blob. With `repeated(.[] | .downloadId; "ABCA01479FCAB77D0A8A5C499D5ABAA147E97B47")
` I'm getting an error `repeated/2 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1`.

Comment: Did you include the def of repeated BEFORE its invocation?

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure what you meant but I combined them and it returns true as it should but returns nothing if false.

Comment: I copied it properly. But I guess I don't need it to return false. I can work with just true. Thank you.

Comment: That works wonderfully. Thanks again. I haven't done anything past simple filters so working with variables in jq takes me longer. You saved me a lot of time.

Comment: @user2328273 : Don't forget to give valueable reputation points to the people that help you. You can both up-vote the answer and accept it. If you're really happy, you can go and upvote other answers too ;-) . I always love reading @peak's `jq` code. I learn so much. I am not worthy!